# Mail server for windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, postfix, email-server

Are there any mail server like postfix ( in linux) in windows server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which one you look for free or commercial ? You can use [hhMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) for free one, I've been using it for year, and always satisfy me. It also support SpamAssasin for additional spam engine checker.
If you look for commercial, then nothing more powerful then Microsoft Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

What about http://james.apache.org/ ? It can store the messages in the database if you need to :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2003 has a built-in POP3/SMTP mail server: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Windows_POP3_Service.html.

If you want something more powerful, the Microsoft solution is, of course, [Exchange](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange).

Comment: But bear in mind that the POP3 component has been dropped from Windows 2008, which might be important if you plan on using it and then upgrading in future...

Comment: what open source tools ?

Comment: The POP3/SMTP components are built-in, there's no additional cost in using them if you already own a Windows Server 2003 license.